# How can I anchor an element/img on a specific part of the screen on a div?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I've been trying to find a way to position my image and "anchor" it so that it stays on that position no matter the screen size

[image]

The image is currently in a div as below:

```
.titleContainer{
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;

display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
justify-content: flex-start;
align-items: center;
```

The background(red and yellow) is outside of the titleContainer as below:

```
.rightBackground{
width: 70%;
height: 100%;

position: absolute;
background-color: var(--red-color);
left: 30%;
z-index: -1;
```

}

and there is also a left version as well.

The image/title is setup as:

```
.titleLogo{
width: auto;
height: auto;
max-width: 300px;
max-height: 150px;

margin-left: 20%;
```

This obviously doesn't work as when I resize my screen, I get something like this
[image]

Does anyone know tricks to get my image to anchor on the red/yellow line?